# What if I delete rows from Django queryset and then filter again?

Tags: python, django, database, orm, django-queryset

Consider the following code:

```
questions = Question.objects.only('id', 'pqa_id', 'retain')
del_questions = questions.filter(retain=False)
# Some computations on del_questions
del_questions.delete()
add_questions = questions.filter(pqa_id=None)
```

Will `add_questions` not contain questions with `retain=False`? I.e. is `questions` object re-evaluated when we run `delete()` on its subset `del_questions`?

Comment: You constructed a *new* queryset by adding a `.filter(..)` clause, so it will perform a new query. But note that here `questions` itself is *never* evaluated in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: you here use different `QuerySet`s, so you will here, by creating a copy, make another query. If you would use the same `QuerySet`, Django will remove the cache, and so it will *re-evaluate* the `QuerySet`. It is however possible to let objects temporarily survive a `.delete()` call, due to caching in another `QuerySet` that was evaluated *before*.

> is `questions` object re-evaluated when we run `delete()` on its subset del_questions

`questions`s is *never* evaluated in the first place. A `QuerySet` is iterable and in case you iterate over it (or fetch the length, or something else), will result in a query. But if you write `Model.objects.all().filter(foo=3)` then Django will *not* first "evaluate" the `.all()` by fetching all `Model` objects into memory.

A `QuerySet` is in essence a tool to build a query, by chaining operations and each time constructing a *new* queryset. Eventually you can evaluate one of the querysets.

Here by apply a `.filter(..)` for the two calls. We thus constructed two *different* `QuerySet`s, and so if you evaluate the former, then this will not result in any caching in the latter.

A second important note is that a `.delete()` does *not* evaluate the queryset, and thus does not cache the results. If we inspect the [**`.delete()`** method [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.1.x/django/db/models/query.py#L641), we see:

> ```
> def delete(self):
>     """Delete the records in the current QuerySet."""
>     assert self.query.can_filter(), \
>         "Cannot use 'limit' or 'offset' with delete."
>
>     if self._fields is not None:
>         raise TypeError("Cannot call delete() after .values() or .values_list()")
>
>     del_query = self._chain()
>
>     # The delete is actually 2 queries - one to find related objects,
>     # and one to delete. Make sure that the discovery of related
>     # objects is performed on the same database as the deletion.
>     del_query._for_write = True
>
>     # Disable non-supported fields.
>     del_query.query.select_for_update = False
>     del_query.query.select_related = False
>     del_query.query.clear_ordering(force_empty=True)
>
>     collector = Collector(using=del_query.db)
>     collector.collect(del_query)
>     deleted, _rows_count = collector.delete()
>
>     # Clear the result cache, in case this QuerySet gets reused.
>     self._result_cache = None
>     return deleted, _rows_count
> ```

With `self._chain()`, one creates a *copy* of the querset. So even if this would change the state of a `QuerySet`, then it would not change the state of this `QuerySet`.

Another interesting part is `self._result_cache = None`, here Django *resets* the cache. So if the queryset was already evaluated *before* you called `.delete()` (for example you materialized the queryset before calling `.delete()`), then it will *remove* that cache. So if you would reevaluate the `QuerySet`, this would result in another query to fetch the items.

There is however a scenario where data can still get outdated. For example the following:

```
questions = Question.objects.all()  # create a queryset
list(questions)                     # materialize the result
questions2 = questions.all()        # create a copy of this queryset
questions2.delete()                 # remove the entries
```

If we now would call `list(questions)`, we thus obtain the elements in the cache of `questions`, and this `QuerySet` is *not* invalidated, so the elements "survive" a `.delete()` from another queryset (a copy from this one, although that is not necessary, a simply `Questions.objects.all().delete()` would also do the trick).